# Online Routing Service (non-Google)

Tags: routing, web-service

im currently blueprinting something i wanna develop. Thinking about the stuff that would be needed, i figured out that i would need to have a pgRouting/postGis Database somewhere. The program i wanna make, should calculate data and return the shortest path.

Is there any online service who offer this kind of service (an accessible pgRouting/postGIS Database)?? even for a fee ??
Since i couldn't find one im asking here.

Thanks a lot.

---

Update from comments:

I want to develop an app that USES a routing service, to display the (elsewhere) routed data on the phone. Like oh i am here, thisService->please tell me how to get from x to y.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear. Why do you need an online service for your application? Do you have your own network/road data?

Comment: Ok let me explain it a little more. lets say the app monitors your gps position and based on "some opensource postgis/pgrouting service" you can get back a specific route to point x, that you were interested in. i know that i or "the company" ( in this case its me since i am a single developer) has to set up a server providing that data, that i think my users will need. Thats where my question comes in: Im asking if theres some kind of service like this. Like a universal pgrouting/postgis database that one can access. just like google maps. but NOT google maps ^^ Because i wanna use openlayers

Comment: do you think openstreetmap offers this kind of service ?

Comment: Do you want to develop a routing webservice or do you want to just use one? Or are you planning to let the client do the routing?

Comment: Check OpenRouteService: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#ORS_.22API.22

Comment: Ok sorry my question wasnt really specific. I want to develop an app that USES a routing service, to display the (elsewhere) routed data on the phone. Like oh i am here, thisService->please tell me how to get from x to y. Oh thanks for the answer. The client will be an iphone, i have seen PC get stuck doing those type of calculation, so the answer to client routing is no :D

Comment: I'll check it out. EDIT: @underdark: could you post this as an answer, so i can accept it. You pointed me exactly to the place i was looking for :). Thanks alot. Eventhough the name is kind of selfexplanatory *facepalm*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenRouteService offers an API for routing based on OSM: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#ORS_.22API.22

Comment: Here's an addition to your answer. OSM has made a list available with all online routers. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters

Comment: In my case the 'YOURS' service suits my needs best. I can download a single .gpx file with only my route in it. Which i can then display on a GML Layer on my OpenLayers map inside the app. I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**MapQuest OPEN API** has this service - it does cover a larger area than the current OpenRouteService.

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/directions-service

Note: the Directions and Routes are only as good as the quality of the basedata - sometimes [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) is better and in less popular areas worse than other Routing services out there